# Plots touching each other

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create three box plots that touch each other (no space between boxes).  I know that the problem are margins for ticks and labels (even if there are none), so I just don't know how to remove them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$p$,ticks=none,at={(0,0)}]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ticks=none,at={(5cm,0)}]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ticks=none,at={(10cm,0)}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: You might also look at groupplots, [trim axis left] and [trim axis right] and possibly \pgfresetboundingbox.

Answer (score 1):

`scale only axis=true` solved the problem.

I just posted if anyone else has the same problem.  In case administrators think this is inappropriate, please erase the message.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with numbers and I got this. Is that ok for you?

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$p$,ticks=none,at={(0,0)}]
 \end{axis}

 \begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ticks=none,at={(3.4cm,0cm)}]
 \end{axis}

 \begin{axis}[width=5cm,height=4cm,xlabel=$t$,ticks=none,at={(6.8cm,0)}]
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have already solved the problem.  Please see the answer I posted two hours before yours.

Comment: I saw it alrdy. Suit yourself! :)